# can I input addresses in other languages like Chinese to do geocoding?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

instead of the address like 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1426 commonwealth avenue&key=AIzaSyCUFCvt4Xs7GYmeXHpk4Wb13Bt1-E12Rik
can I input Chinese as the address? like 北京市天安门?
I tried https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address="北京市天安门"&region=cn&key=AIzaSyCUFCvt4Xs7GYmeXHpk4Wb13Bt1-E12Rik
But it couldn't work
Thank you very much!

Comment: It works for me. No idea why it wouldn't work for you.

Comment: Really? you just use ---  "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address="北京市天安门"&region=cn&key=AIzaSyCUFCvt4Xs7GYmeXHpk4Wb13Bt1-E12Rik"  and it can work??????

Comment: And can you show me the results? Thank you!

Comment: http://pastie.org/10289051

Comment: What the hell!!!!!!!

Comment: Looks to me like Tiananmen, not hell, but then I don't know...

Comment: HAHAHA, Thank you anyway. Seems it cannot work in China

Answer (score 0):

Try to send the request to the host `maps.google.cn` :

https://maps.google.cn/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=%E5%8C%97%E4%BA%AC%E5%B8%82%E5%A4%A9%E5%AE%89%E9%97%A8&region=cn&key=AIzaSyCUFCvt4Xs7GYmeXHpk4Wb13Bt1-E12Rik

At least for the Javascript-API this is the recommended host(maybe it also applies to the geocoding-API)

For me the URL above doesn't work(maybe it works only from china), but when I use a chinese webproxy I get a result:

http://bbs.ynu.edu.cn/proxy/browse.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fmaps.google.cn%2Fmaps%2Fapi%2Fgeocode%2Fxml%3Faddress%3D%25E5%258C%2597%25E4%25BA%25AC%25E5%25B8%2582%25E5%25A4%25A9%25E5%25AE%2589%25E9%2597%25A8%26region%3Dcn%26key%3DAIzaSyCUFCvt4Xs7GYmeXHpk4Wb13Bt1-E12Rik&b=28&f=norefer

Comment: @kaho: **ditu.google.cn** works too for me but at least the documentation for the javascript-API says: [**maps.google.cn**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#GoogleMapsChina)